# How to call flutter engine methods from another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, flutter

I'm using flutter desktop for linux. I'm calling a method called `MarkTextureFrameAvailable` that is supposed to mark a texture to be rerendered by the engine. Since I'm programming a video player, I need to call `MarkTextureFrameAvailable` from the player's thread. The problem is that the engine forces me to call `MarkTextureFrameAvailable` (and any other engine method) from the thread which created the engine.

You can see that all calls to the engine end up in the shell which always do checks to see if the calls are being made from the same thread that created the call:

```
task_runners_.GetPlatformTaskRunner()->RunsTasksOnCurrentThread()
```

(https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/shell/common/shell.cc#L838)

This is how I'm creating the flutter engine:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  //..

  flutter::FlutterWindowController flutter_controller(icu_data_path);

  // Start the engine.
  if (!flutter_controller.CreateWindow(800, 600, "Flutter WebRTC Demo", assets_path,
                                       arguments)) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  // Register any native plugins.
  FlutterWebRTCPluginRegisterWithRegistrar(
      flutter_controller.GetRegistrarForPlugin("FlutterWebRTCPlugin"));

  // Run until the window is closed.
  flutter_controller.RunEventLoop();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

as you can see, the thread which creates the engine gets blocked by `flutter_controller.RunEventLoop();` which is the only place I could put an event dispatcher that forced things to be executed from main's thread. I don't like this idea. Even though `RunEventLoopWithTimeout` exists, I need to put a timeout and keep checking in a queue for `MarkTextureFrameAvailable` calls. I don't think this is optimal.

So how should I call `MarkTextureFrameAvailable` from the main thread?

I found an example of usage of `MarkTextureFrameAvailable` here: https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/flutter-webrtc/blob/desktop/common/src/flutter_video_renderer.cc#L90 and **it looks like it's another thread which calls it. How is it possible? When I do, I get a FATAL error, but he does and it works?**

I spent two days trying to figure out which thread calls OnFrame on this example but couldn't find out because it uses https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/libwebrtc which uses google's webrtc: https://github.com/JumpingYang001/webrtc which is too big for me to find where OnFrame is called from. But it must me from a thread. How is it possible?

Comment: If you want an alternative to using a timeout to run periodic tasks in the main runloop, you could submit a Flutter engine PR to expose glfwPostEmptyEvent via a wrapper. Having a way to wake the main runloop is a reasonable addition to the GLFW embedding API.

Comment: @smorgan I'll try that, but I'm astonished on how this example: https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/flutter-webrtc/blob/desktop/common/src/flutter_video_renderer.cc#L90 does without RunEventLoopWithTimeOut. Since he blocks the main thread with `flutter_controller.RunEventLoop()`, then for sure `MarkTextureFrameAvailable` must be being called from another thread, which should be impossible!

Comment: Quick caveat before my comment -- never heard of Flutter, know very little about Linux, and I'm on mobile so definitely not looking through the code right now. Hopefully I can still be of help. :) The example you gave has their video renderer inherit from what looks like the main flutter renderer instance. Their ``OnRender`` is a virtual override of Flutter so it gets invoked by the Flutter thread.

Answer (score 3):

See my comment for the caveat to this answer. It appears that the example project you provided accomplishes this with a simple trick. They create a new class that [inherits](https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/flutter-webrtc/blob/desktop/common/include/flutter_video_renderer.h#L15) the flutter renderer class, overriding `OnFrame` among other things. When that override gets called it's in the context of the Flutter thread and so works as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much by your effort to help! However, the class from Flutter that it subclasses is `Texture,` which does not have onFrame method. That onFrame method is from `RTCVideoRenderer` which has nothing to do with Flutter.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/flutter-webrtc/blob/desktop/common/include/flutter_webrtc.h). Looks like they do override Flutter, and possibly using a supported plugin system. My best advice would be to read Flutter documentation. I would be willing to bet if you placed a BP in OnFrame it would be in the context of the Flutter thread as expected.

Comment: I'm aleady using the plugin system and I've read the documentation, there's no onFrame method. The only thing from Flutter in FlutterVideoRenderer class is Texture, which has no onFrame method. Actually I found where onFrame is defined, and is a thing from WebRTC library as you can see here https://github.com/JumpingYang001/webrtc/search?q=onFrame&unscoped_q=onFrame

Comment: @LucasZanella Pickle Rick is right, `FlutterVideoRenderer` [inherits](https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/flutter-webrtc/blob/desktop/common/include/flutter_video_renderer.h) from two classes - `Texture` (line 16) and `RTCVideoRenderer<scoped_refptr<RTCVideoFrame>>` (line 17) (C++ allows multiple inheritance) and then it overrides `OnFrame` method (line 24). When `OnFrame` event is fired, it is executed in the context of your main thread.

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat but OnFrame is not from Flutter, it's from RTCVideoRenderer which is not from Flutter

Comment: has anyone solve this? I'm also encounter the same problem.